# Add color picker to Umbraco Form Settings

Tags: forms, colors, umbraco, background-color, umbraco-forms

I want to add a color picker to umbraco for setting, so when the User create a new form he/she is able to add a background color, text color from the form setting. I have checked for solutions but there is no proper solution for this. i could only find of adding css class in it. Could someone please advice me on this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create your own custom Umbraco Forms control to do that.  There's documentation at https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Add-ons/UmbracoForms/Developer/Extending/Adding-a-Fieldtype that guides you through that task.

Comment: Thank you so much Robert, i will check the link. Great!